# MyClass.class.getField() возвращает лишние поля

Tags: java, android, рефлексия

Есть приложение, в котором при помощи рефлексии получаются поля классов, но есть небольшая проблема, на разных устройствах срабатывает он по разном, и главное что от версии API это сильно не зависит (по крайней мере замечено не было). И на некоторых устройствах он возвращает на два поля больше, такие как:

```
public static transient volatile com.android.tools.ir.runtime.IncrementalChange com.my.myapp.db.DBH$TravelTotals$DC.$change

public static final long com.my.myapp.db.DBH$TravelTotals$DC.serialVersionUID
```

Из-за такого поведения нарушается нормальная работа приложения, точнее на этих устройствах оно впринципе не работает ибо поля могут быть `null` или иметь запредельные значения, не предназначенные для БД. Как их можно убрать или переназначить? Костыли

Comment: как правило поля энтити класса, связанные с колонками таблицы имеют соответствующую аннотацию

Comment: Если бы они там были, я бы не спрашивал. Решение нашлось: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36556093/android-studio-2-0-update-public-static-volatile-com-android-tools-fd-runtime, только мне пришлось полностью отрубить Instant run

Comment: Instant Run же вроде ускоряет отладку - в релизе его не должно быть по идее? Второй момент - не представляю зачем заносить в базу статические поля? Если рефлексию реализуете вы, то можно отсеять их по `static`.

Comment: @woesss На данном этапе факт в том что приложение не возможно отлаживать когда оно не работает. По Поводу отсеивания это уже интересный момент, нужно обдумать как это реализовать. По поводу записи в БД: реалии таковы что при помощи рефлексии (может я ошибся с названием) реализовано создание таблиц для базы данных и в тех случаях, когда у нас нет этих двух полей, всё отрабатывает чётко, а вот когда есть, тогда проевляются некоторые проблемы и соответственно БД не может быть создана.

Comment: Вы так и не сказали - ваш код разбирает поля или сторонняя ОРМ-библиотека? Если второе, то может стоит перейти на `Room`? Если код ваш , то добавьте проверку поля: `Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())`. Также стоит отсеять `transient` - модификатор был придуман для исключения полей при сериализации, поэтому многие библиотеки тоже используют его как исключение из обработки. Ещё можно отсеять `field.isSyntetic()` - синтетические поля генерирует компилятор для поддержки некоторых возможностей языка, в базе они тоже не нужны, если в проекте не используется какой-нибудь странный препроцессор.

Comment: @woesss, я бы с радостью перешел на Room, но это на данный момент будет очень затратно, нет это не ОРМ. Спасибо, я попробую реализовать так как вы говорите. Спасибо.